# MYSQL query using count function

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a function where I have to retrieve from a database that stores direct graphs. I have a graph table with columsn, graph name and graphID. and a node table that has columns nodeid, graphid, and has exitnode and entrynodes. I tried using the count statement to count the number of nodes that each graph has to return the name but it keeps returning empty sets. Can someone look over my query and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT
    graphName
  FROM 
    graphs 
  WHERE graphID 
    IN ( 
      SELECT 
         graphID 
       FROM 
         nodes 
       WHERE count(entryNode, exitNode) = 2
    );
```

Comment: You may need to be more explicit. Is `entryNode` and `exitNode` a column in `graphs` or `nodes`?

Comment: It is a a column in nodes, the graphs columns is only the graphName and graphID

Comment: select g.graphname, (select count(*) from nodes n where n.graphid = g.graphid) from graphs g

Comment: The count function returns the number of total nodes in each graph, I would like to count the entryNodes and exitNodes, if the count of both is 2 then return the graph. Can I count by using the syntax count(entryNodes exitNode)

Comment: @Ace8 how do you know if it is an entry or exit node?

Comment: @maraca you know if it is a entry node or exit node if the element is 1

Answer (score 0):

You can take use of the nodeid:

```
SELECT g.graphName, COUNT(DISTINCT nen.nodeid), COUNT(DISTINCT nex.nodeid)
FROM graphs g
  JOIN nodes nen on nen.graphID = g.graphID AND nen.entryNode=1
  JOIN nodes nex on nex.graphID = g.graphID AND nex.exitNode=1
GROUP BY g.graphName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT nen.nodeid)=2 and COUNT(DISTINCT nex.nodeid)=2
```